# Validating input and throwing error

Tags: apex, javascript, inputfield, code, isblank

So I have this field input in my UI, I need it to throw an error if it is left blank, but it is not. This is my code

```
<div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-align_absolute-center">
        <lightning:input aura:id="matrixName" name="Matrix Name" maxlength="80"
                         label="Matrix Name" placeholder="Matrix Name" />
        <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.inputError))}">
            {!v.inputError}
        </aura:if>
    </div>
```

My controller

```
doCreateMatrix: function (component) {
    var matrixInput = component.find("matrixName");

    if (!matrixInput) {
        console.log("matrixName has not been found");
        return;
    }

    var matrixName = matrixInput.get('v.value');

    if (!matrixName || matrixName.trim().length === 0) {
        //Handle BLANK matrixName
        component.set("v.inputError", "Name cannot be blank");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use `required="true"`? The component can validate itself.

Comment: I added the the condition required="true", should I remove the aura:if because it is still not showing my error message, I added what I have in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard method is to let the component validate itself:

```
    <lightning:input aura:id="matrixName" name="Matrix Name" maxlength="80"
                     label="Matrix Name" placeholder="Matrix Name" 
                     required="true" />
```

This will also add the required askerisk (a red `*`) to the field's label, indicating it is required.

In your code, make sure you check validity before submitting data to the server:

```
var matrixField = component.find("matrixName");
matrixField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
if(!matrixField.checkValidity()) {
  // Optional message if you want
  alert("Please fill out the required field."); 
  return; // Don't continue past this point
}
```

Comment: Yea for some reason, the alert is not appearing on screen, I have exactly what you have

Comment: I think I discovered why, Ill share shortly

Comment: i had to add the attribute to my original code     <aura:attribute name="inputError" type="String" default="" />